# How do I Install Xcode 6 or 7 on an external drive?

Tags: installation, xcode6

The capacity of my SSD is just 60Gb, and I have just over 5Gb of free space at the moment. Is there a way to install Xcode directly on the external drive? Or to do so I'd have first to make this drive bootable and boot my system from it?

Answer (score 8):

There are various possible solutions, including, making use of symlinks, dual booting two versions of macOS (one on external SSD), and many more.

But the best way I found was to create a new macOS user and change its home directory to external SSD (by going to advanced user settings under Users & Groups System Preferences).

The exact steps I followed:

1. Create a new APFS partition on external SSD with 100GB storage. (say NewVol)
2. Create new macOS user and change its home directory to /Volume/NewVol/user
3. Logged into the new user with external SSD connected, and installed xcode in ~/Application. (i.e. the local Application folder, not /Application)

Why this works best is because you don't need to manually manage symlinks, also symlinks might create problems during builds. All the required files (including builds and temporary files) are stored in user directory, so no space occupied on internal drive. Also, no hassle of installing a complete separate OS, and going through cycles of reboots to switch the OS.

Comment: This solution is really the best. Simple, fast and really works. Thanks a lot. I was about to buy a new Mac when I found this answer. Thanks my friend, saved me many dollars

Comment: @ThiagoSilva This made my day, thanks. Also, you can turn on "fast user switching" (Sys Pref -> Users -> login options -> Show fast user switch) to quickly switch between external/internal user without logging out.

Comment: Here I can't able to see the Application folder. I have renamed the directory from the home to the external drive. But there I not see the application.

Comment: ^ You need to actually login once into the new user (after changing the home directory, i.e. after performing step 2). After you login once, the relevant user folders will be created, including the local Application folder. If the Application folder is still not visible, manually create one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options you can consider.

Move some files to the external drive, instead of installing applications on it. This would be your best bet, since applications have dependancies. Also, if you run them from your SSD, they will get better performance.

If you absolutely need your files on your SSD, and you can't move them, then I would suggest moving any third party applications to see if you can free up space for Xcode, and run it from your SSD.

If the two options above don't work for you, then you will have to try and work with Xcode. There is no easy way to change the install location. Your option here would be to free up some space temporarily, by moving bigger files to an external drive. Then do the Xcode install in your applications folder. Once that's done, move Xcode to the external drive, and take your files back to your SSD. [Here is](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90219/change-default-installation-location-to-install-xcode) another questions that talks about the same topic.